# Footnote for glossary title

Tags: footnotes, glossaries

How can I add a footnote to the page of glossaries definitions. 
Something like that....Unfortunately this is not working:

```
    \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={Acronimos\footnote{Vestibulum bibendum mollis elit}}]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{malt}{MALT}{tejido linfoide asociado a la mucosa}
\newacronym{pio}{PIO}{presión intraocular}
\newacronym{ossn}{OSSN}{neoplasias escamosas de la superficie ocular}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \gls{malt} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel
scelerisque dui, vitae elementum purus. Mauris aliquam lobortis justo ut
rhoncus. Vestibulum bibendum mollis elit, a eleifend sapien cursus eget. Nullam
vulputate pretium porttitor. Nunc elementum commodo porttitor. Nam vel quam
quis ipsum venenatis elementum \gls{pio} eu id ipsum. Curabitur gravida
pharetra dapibus. Aliquam eleifend nec mi sed pharetra. Ut ut dui volutpat,
luctus est in, maximus nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla convallis dictum nibh, sit amet
dapibus dui posuere id.

\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={Acronimos\footnote{Vestibulum bibendum mollis elit}}]    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the glossary function, or its section title as the problem appears to be, is working by writing content into a file and then later reading the file back in to produce the glossary. Unfortunately, `\footnote` is a [fragile command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands#4747), which means it will not function correctly in this situation. (The problem, in a nutshell, is that TeX expands `\footnote` *before* writing it to the file, when it properly should be expanded when the file is read and the content is actually being typeset.)

To fix it, you must `\protect` the `\footnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{malt}{MALT}{tejido linfoide asociado a la mucosa}
\newacronym{pio}{PIO}{presión intraocular}
\newacronym{ossn}{OSSN}{neoplasias escamosas de la superficie ocular}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \gls{malt} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel
scelerisque dui, vitae elementum purus. Mauris aliquam lobortis justo ut
rhoncus. Vestibulum bibendum mollis elit, a eleifend sapien cursus eget. Nullam
vulputate pretium porttitor. Nunc elementum commodo porttitor. Nam vel quam
quis ipsum venenatis elementum \gls{pio} eu id ipsum. Curabitur gravida
pharetra dapibus. Aliquam eleifend nec mi sed pharetra. Ut ut dui volutpat,
luctus est in, maximus nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla convallis dictum nibh, sit amet
dapibus dui posuere id.

\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={Acronimos\protect\footnote{Vestibulum bibendum mollis elit}}]    

\end{document}
```

Comment: the online platform https://www.overleaf.com/ and also my system compiles the MWE correctly. I tried \protect{} but it cause an error message: Use of \\glossarysection doesn't match its definition.

Comment: Thank you!! It is working. I had an issue with {} in my code.